# why ArgumentParser returns error: Unrecognized arguments?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am using ArgumentParser for js, I need to send string as one of the parameters, but the parser returns this error: Unrecognized arguments: 
-filePath

```
const parser = new ArgumentParser({
  debug: true,
  version: "0.0.1",
  addHelp: true,
  description: "Argparse example",
});
parser.addArgument("-filePath", {
  type: String,
  defaultValue: "try",
  help: "send path to file",
});
function main() {
  try {
    const args = parser.parseArgs();
    console.log("args: ", args);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  console.log("DONE");
}
```

and send args like this:

```
"args": ["-filePath = '../ts.xslx'"]
```

what is the right way to do it? I looked in github official guide but not found anything helpful. what i am missing?

Comment: Which argument parser module is this?

Comment: this one - https://www.npmjs.com/package/argparse

Answer (score 0):

The module you're using is "old-school" enough to only do long options with double dashes.

```
const { ArgumentParser } = require("argparse");

const parser = new ArgumentParser({
  debug: true,
  version: "0.0.1",
  addHelp: true,
  description: "Argparse example",
});

parser.addArgument(["-f", "--filePath"], {
  type: String,
  defaultValue: "try",
  help: "send path to file",
});

console.log(parser.parseArgs());
```

This works with both `-f` and `--filePath`.

```
$ node test.js --filePath foo.js
args:  Namespace { filePath: 'foo.js' }
DONE
$ node test.js -f foo.js
args:  Namespace { filePath: 'foo.js' }
DONE
```